# Why get_allocator returns a copy and not a reference

Tags: c++, c++11, stdvector, allocator

I am using a custom allocator, which has a small simple state internally. When I use it with `std::vector`, I was surprised to see that `get_allocator()` actually returns copy to the allocator.

This is documented here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/get_allocator

What is the reason for this?

One reason I can imagine is that `get_allocator` is a `const` member, I wouldn't mind getting a `const` reference to the allocator. Besided the internal allocator could have been declared `mutable`.

**Am I missing something?
Is there a workaround to get the internal allocator of `std::vector<T, special_allocator<T>>` to inspect the state of the allocator?**

Note: There is also the possibility that if the allocator is stateful then, perhaps one is *supposed* to use references all the way? Like `std::vector<T, special_allocator<T>&>`

Comment: Why can't you inspect the state of the copy?

Comment: @T.C., I can, (and it is a good point) but I was identifying the actual allocator by its address, still I am surprised that I have to make a copy to inspect the state.

Comment: "identifying the actual allocator by its address" — why? The allocator is (typically) a data member in the vector, its address is a simple function of the address of the vector.

Comment: "the possibility that if the allocator is stateful" — a typical allocator state is an address of a shared memory region or other arena where the allocation takes place. Allocators are supposed to be freely copyable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stateful allocators are supposed to copy with retaining their state.

For example, when you pass an allocator for a map, it is rebound to another allocator type, but still retains the state you've passed to it.

Or two distinct containers share allocator state, yet they have different allocator instance.

Typically, you have allocator that has pointer to your state. Make pointer to your state a parameter of allocator constructor, and pass it as a parameter of your container constructor.

Comment: Very detailed answer describing how things are expected to be.